# Compare range of ip addresses with start and end ip address in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ip-address

I have a MySQL table where I store IP ranges. It is setup in the way that I have the start address stored as a long, and the end address (and an id and some other data).
Now I have users adding ranges by inputting a start and end ip address, and I would like to check if the new range is not already (partially) in the database.

I know I can do a between query, but that doesn't seem to work with 2 different columns, and I also cannot figure out how to pass a range to compare it.
Doing it in a loop in PHP is a possibility, but would with a range of e.g. 132.0.0.0-199.0.0.0 be quite a big amount of queries..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say you have the addresses stored as a `long`, I'm assuming you mean you've got them stored such that (say) 10.1.2.3 will be stored as 0x0a010203. In that case, to find if an address is already present, you can do:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ipranges
WHERE (<NEWADDR> >= startaddr)
    AND (<NEWADDR> <= endaddr)
```

and then if you get any rows back, the address is already in the table. (replace `<NEWADDR>` with the new address, of course!)

As for checking overlapping rows, that's only slightly more complicated:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ipranges
WHERE NOT ((<NEWENDADDR> < startaddr) OR (<NEWSTARTADDR> > endaddr))
```

i.e. the new range doesn't overlap the old range provided that either it starts after it, or ends before it.

Comment: the overlap logic was a bit over my head it seems, makes sense to me now, thanks for the help. Had already thought of a nice loop in PHP which was not too inefficient but this is much faster still ofcourse

Answer (score 1):

Both start_address and end_address are longs?  Then why not just convert the IP you're looking for to a long and do `WHERE start_address <= $myip AND end_address >= $myip`?

For a range, just do it three times in the where clause

```
WHERE (start_address <= $startAddress AND end_address >= $startAddress) 
   OR (start_address <= $endAddress AND end_address >= $endAddress) 
   OR (start_address >= $startAddress AND end_address <= $endAddress)
```

The first grouping finds ranges that encompass the start address.  The second one finds ranges that encompass the end address.  That means that there's still a possibility that the range that was inputted is a superset of a range in the db.  That's what the third one checks for.

That should return you all the ranges which intersect your inputted range...

Comment: You don't actually need three cases - it's easier to check for the cases where the ranges *don't* overlap (i.e. the new range is either entirely lower, or entirely higher, than the existing range), then use `NOT` to invert the result :-)

Answer (score 1):

How about storing the IP addres ranges as decimal that way you can do simple checks using the BETWEEN.

4294967295 - 4294967040 -> FFFFFF00 - FFFFFFFF -> 255.255.255.0 - 255.255.255.255

Answer (score 0):

What about something like:

```
SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE
    (start < $new_start AND end > $new_start) OR
    (start > $new_end AND end < $new_end);
```

That should give you all the existing addresses which will overlap the new address.

Comment: What if the new range completely surrounds the old range? For example, if old range was (start=99,end=100) and the new range is ($new_start=1,$new_end=200)? I don't think your query would return this result :-(

Comment: So then it's a simple additional clause:
` OR (start >= $new_start AND end <= $new_end)`